# Bistatic radar equation for moving objects

Tags: doppler-effect, distance, radio-frequency, radar

From my understanding, and correct me if I'm wrong, the bistatic radar equation assumes that the transmitter and the receiver are separated by a distance $L$, and that the transmitter and receiver are static, while the target is moving at a distance $R_r$ from the receiver and a distance $R_t$ from the transmitter.
$$P_r = {{P_t G_t G_r \sigma \lambda^2}\over{{(4\pi)}^3 R_t^2R_r^2}}$$

Hence my question, does the bistatic radar equation is different when the transmitter, the receiver, and the target are all moving? Does the equation change only when one want to consider Doppler effect?

Answer (score 1):

The bistatic radar equation is valid for a point target in vacuum with effectively infinite bandwidth transmit/receive hardware and as such it is time independent, and thus velocity independent as well. In reality when anything is moving (transmitter, target, receiver) *things* do change, for example, the multipath environment, scattering cross section, glint, etc., and the received power as calculated from this equation is less important than the time varying enviroment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the time was going to show up in the equation when changing the $\lambda$ for considering Doppler effect.

Comment: Oh I see. In that you are right but think of the scale how much *in practice* $\lambda$ actually changes. If the target moves at 10km/sec, a very fast target, then it is only about $2\times 10/(0.3\times 10^6)$, or  maybe ~6o  ppm, and it is completely negligible when compared to any other effect.

Comment: and note too that if you are concerned about the the frequency dependence of the Friis's  equation then you should not use antenna gain in it because that is also frequency dependent for a given aperture $A_{eff}$: $G \sim \frac{4\pi A_{eff}}{\lambda ^2}$

Comment: Yet, the shift in frequency is still high enough to be measurable for calculating velocity or range of the target?

Comment: Yes, because frequency measurement  resolution (and accuracy) depends on the *length* of time the target is illuminated and not on anything else. 1.5m/sec corresponds to 1kHz (0.1ppm) shift at 10GHz (X-band radar), and you can get very good estimate of 1kHz shift with 1msec coherent integration. Doppler shift cannot be used to measure range, at least not with a single receiver.

Comment: Is there a version of this equation for the SNR with the dependance over $f$? I'm unable to find a good reference talking about this, they always separate the doppler analysis from the radar equation, always leaving $\lambda$ in the equation.

Comment: To get $f$ dependence of the received power replace $G$ with $A_{eff}$ in the bi (or mono) static equation, and substitute $\lambda$ with $c/f$, there is nothing else for narrow-band system. For a wideband or ultra wideband even the effective aperture is frequency dependent and the best you can do is to break it up into smaller, effectively freq independent spectral bands. And do not forget the potentially very strong frequency dependence of the radar cross section $\sigma$!